# How to set a variable in React/TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Part 2 of wanting to absolutely die while learning React/TS.

So I'm in some code that looks like this.
Basically I've tried in 3 different ways to set a variable.

1. Closure. It doesn't work. This is really a remarkable feat of engineering to break JS basics like this. Literally every single line of code is encapsulated in this `React.FC` function and that doesn't seem to matter.
2. useRef. It seems to work but why do I need this to set a variable.
3. useState. Pretty sure this is for the DOM and not simple flags.

So here it is. 20k hours of Javascript under my belt and I cannot set a variable in React/TS.

```
const MyElement: React.FC = () => {
  
  // This one suffers from scope issues, somehow. 
  let currentRow1: HTMLElement | null;
  // I guess this works but God does it feel wrong
  const currentRow2 = React.useRef<null | HTMLElement>(null);
  // Pretty sure this is for DOM rendering anyway
  const [currentRow3, setCurrentRow3] = React.useState<null | HTMLElement>(null)
 
  // Here's a handler for an event
  const handleClickEvent = () => {
    // Ok closure works here..? huh
    unsetCurrentRow1()
    currentRow1 = somelement
    // This works, but why would I want to do this
    currentRow2.current = somelement
    // At least I'm pretty sure this is not what this is for
    setCurrentRow3(somelement)
  }

  const unsetCurrentRow = () => {
     if(currentRow1) // Undefined!!!
        currentRow1 = null;
     currentRow2.current = null; // Yes
     // Again, most likely wrong altogether 
     setCurrentRow3(null)
  }
}
```

So I feel like I'm taking crazy pills. Do I not understand TS or do I not understand React? Why doesn't closure work? Why am I forced to use an object that has a property called current? What the heck am I doing?

Comment: This feels like a rant in disguise. If you want to keep state in a component, `useState` should work fine. Refs do something different -- keep references to elements in the DOM. That's more than "setting a variable". What are you trying to achieve here, exactly? Please share a [mcve] (include the JSX) -- pseudocode is hard to follow.

Comment: "Why am I forced to use an object that has a property called current" -->Because that is how useRef is implemented, you are stressing too much about that. useState for storing some value in it which you want to persist across renders (I never needed to put a DOM node inside)

Comment: You **have** to use `.current` whenever you use `useRef`, that's the API.  What are you trying to do?  Why are you tracking HTML elements anyway?  Why aren't you using the render and tracking indices?  React is meant to be declarative and reaching into the DOM manually is more of an escape hatch than the intended method.

Comment: IIRC, there isn't actually a dom element available until after the react element renders, so useRef lets you get the dom element after the react element renders and do stuff with it in useEffect or callbacks. Also the element is in the current property.

Comment: useState screws me because it is async. I want to set a var to save which row was clicked. I cannot use props because I have 0 access to this row, period. It is Material UI and they control rendering and component creation. I cannot pass props to it. So I must look outside in some other control space

Comment: @tester778899 That's exactly what useState is for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "useState. Pretty sure this is for the DOM and not simple flags."

You're definitely wrong on this. It's for any small or large bit of data that you want to persist between renders.

And in general you want to avoid directly referencing DOM elements if you can at all avoid it. You probably don't need to for the vast majority of simple things.

---

In a React functional component, the entire function is executed anytime a re-render happens.

That fact has some consequences. The most important of which is that any variable declaration in your component is redeclared in a brand new scope on each render.

That means if you do:

```
let someVar = 0;
```

And have an event handler that runs something like:

```
function onWhatever() {
  someVar = someVar + 1;
}
```

Then when the component re-renders, `let someVar = 0` is executed, ignoring any previous value because it's not in scope. Then a new event handler function is created based on that new variable.

So all you are doing is updating the `someVar` in your local scope, that will get completely discarded when the component re-renders.

This is all a *very* good thing. It allows you treat variables you need for *this render* differently from values that need to persist.

---

*State* is something that persists on the component. Then your functional component rendering function can ask React "What is the state for this component?" and map the result to a local variable used for that render execution.

You want state for almost any value that should be tracked and updated between renders. And the cool thing is that when state updates, any components that depend on that state are automatically re-rendered. This is very important so that React can know when rendering is required.

It's important to work this way because you may have many of this component on your page, react keeps the state in the component tree to know which component has which state even through many re-renders when the function scope is re-created and re-executed.

---

Another thing that's mixed up in this is refs. Refs are a container for any value. The primary use case is to grab a *reference* to a rendered element in order to do something with it.

For example:

```
const myInputFieldRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)

return (
  <div>
    <input ref={myInputFieldRef} />
    <button onClick={() => alert(myInputFieldRef.current.value)}>Submit</button>
  </div>
)
```

By using a ref we can access that element directly in callbacks and interact with it imperatively. The reason refs are wrapped in an object with a `current` property is so that the ref may be passed around and set just once, but what it's referencing may change. This way you can pass the ref once, change its value a hundred times, and whenever you ask the ref for its value it will give the *current* value.

You can also create a self managed ref as you have done, which has its uses. But you probably want state instead unless you know for a fact that won't work for some reason.

---

You've confused these two concepts.

It's hard to tell what you are trying to do, but I think want to want is a `useState` that tracks the current row, as an index or id (`number`), and that's it. You can then use that change your rendering based on what's current.

Something like:

```
const rows = ['a', 'b', 'c']

function FooComponent() {
  const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = React.useState<number | null>(null)

  return (
    <div>
      {rows.map((name, index) => (
        <div
          key={name}
          onClick={() => setCurrentRow(index)}
          style={{ backgroundColor: currentRow === index ? 'red' : 'white' }}
        >
          Row {name}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

In this example, you click rows to make them selected and turn red.

Comment: This answer is much too high quality for this slightly rant-ish question :)

Comment: I started with "git gud" but decided I could do better.

Comment: Well it helped so I'm glad you made that choice. If you want to know why it sounded ranty, I think I'm just pissy because I've written in JS, C, C++, blabla, and none of them felt so difficult. Like, I had no idea that all of those variables inside the function were reset each time, even though as soon as I read that, I remember the exact video I watched about it. It's just so not obvious, yet now it's totally obvious. It's because everything is inside a function, and I thought that was just some ugly syntax way of declaring a component, kind of like functions before we had classes.

Comment: That’s the beauty of react function components. They are just functions. And hooks are just functions that _hook_ into something external. If you understand the semantics of JavaScript and closures, it’s actually pretty simple.